# Unique rows in join result

Tags: mysql, join, unique

I have a tables of `delas` and `curencies` look like this

```
curecnies
id,code

pairs (the available pairs of curencies )
id  to_sell to_buy

deals 
id
user_id
pair_id
amount_to_sell
amount_to_buy
```

So I need to get all match deals which can execute , but I am can not get the unique matches.

Here is my sql query

```
select *
from deals as d1
join deals d2
    on d1.sell_amount = d2.buy_amount and d1.buy_amount = d2.sell_amount
```

i am getting result look like this
id | user_id | pair_id | amount_to_buy | amount_to_sell | id | user_id | pair_id | amount_to_buy | amount_to_sell

```
1|2|1|1000|3000|2|1|2|3000|1000
2|1|2|3000|1000|1|2|1|1000|3000
```

Comment: Please show us by way of sample data what is not unique in your result set.

Comment: I am getting 2 deals row as one result row repeatedly

Comment: What do you consider 2 deals?  You are matching two deals together, so how do you want to report that?  Do you want to report one record, or do you want two records, one for each side of the match?

Comment: I want that the consider 2 deals will be unique.

Comment: So you want to report _two_ records, or one record?

Comment: i am getting result look like this
id | user_id | pair_id | amount_to_buy | amount_to_sell | id | user_id | pair_id | amount_to_buy | amount_to_sell 
1|2|1|1000|3000|3000|1000
2|1|2|3000|1000|1000|3000

do you understood ?))

Comment: No one can help you if no one can understand you.

Answer (score 0):

You may try using a least/greatest trick here:

```
SELECT t1.*, t2.*
FROM
(
    SELECT DISTINCT
        LEAST(d1.id, d2.id) AS d1_id,
        GREATEST(d1.id, d2.id) AS d2_id
    FROM deals AS d1
    INNER JOIN deals d2
        ON d1.sell_amount = d2.buy_amount AND
           d1.buy_amount = d2.sell_amount
) d
INNER JOIN deals t1
    ON d.d1_id = t1.id
INNER JOIN deals t2
    ON d.d2_id = t2.id;
```

The basic idea here is that the subquery labelled `d` finds a single pair of matched deal IDs, using a least/greatest trick.  Then, we join twice to the `deals` table again to bring in the full information for each member of that deal pair.

Comment: not, I want to get 2 deals in one rows, but not second (see in body of question)

Comment: @YurGasparyan Try my updated answer.  It should not return a single row only for each pair of matched deal records.